# What is the meaning of my last name, Явтушенко?

Tags: значения, ономастика

I'm Argentine with a Ukrainian last name, originally written Явтушенко. My Russian father and grandmother are deceased (and they didn't have a clue as to its meaning — they weren't Ukrainian speakers). I know that the ending *-шенко* is very common in Ukraine, but that, in addition to a song called "Where do you go, Явтуше?" (partially translated) is all I know.

What's the meaning of my last name, Явтушенко?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Явтушенко is a family name based on the personal name Явтух and the suffix -енко ("son of"), so Явтушенко is "son of Явтух". There's also another family name that's more familiar to Russian ears and has the same origins — Евтушенко.

Явтух is a short form of the name Евстихий, which has Greek origins and is translated into Russian as "счастливый, преуспевающий".

---

It seems that the form Евтихий is a more popular name of the same origin. Here's an [article on Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9):

> **Евти́хий** (греч. Εὐτυχής, Εὐτύχιος, букв. «счастливый», «великодушный», «весёлый») — мужское имя греческого происхождения.

These names were given to children based on the calendar of Orthodox Saints (святцы), so in the Wikipedia page, you'll see a number of Orthodox Saints who had this name.

Comment: Thanks, very much. It seems you solved my problem. I didn't know that the suffix -енко was "son of" either. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Well, strictly saying it's not "son of", but "a suffix that shows father-to-son relationship".